# Determinar si un numero de dos digitos pertenece a la serie fibonacci

Tags: python, python-2.x

Necesito determinar si un número de dos dígitos pertenece a la serie fibonacci, tengo el siguiente código:

```
'''Leer un número de dos dígitos y determinar si pertenece a la serie de Fibonacci. Con ciclos.'''

numero1 = int(raw_input("Digite un numero de dos digitos: "))

if numero1 > 9 and numero1 <=99:

    inicial = 0
    numero = 1
    ultimo = 0
    penultimo = 0

    while numero1 <= 100:
        penultimo = ultimo
        ultimo = numero
        numero = penultimo + ultimo 

    if numero1 == ultimo:
        print "Si pertenece a las serie Fibonacci."


    else:
        print "El numero no pertenece a la serie Fibonacci."

else:
    print "Debe ingresar un numero de dos digitos"
```

Pero no consigo que me muestre lo que necesito, simplemente no imprime nada.

Comment: ¿Y exactamente que te muestra? Porque como yo lo veo ese código se queda en un ciclo infinito en lugar de terminar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los problemas están en el ciclo `while`, esta parte de tu programa es la que realmente se encarga de obtener los valores de la sucesión de Fibonacci de forma iterativa.

El primer problema viene en la línea `while numero1 <= 100`. `numero1` es el numero procedente del `input` y **jamás se modifica en el ciclo**. Como `numero1` siempre es menor de 100 por el `if` previo, `numero1 <= 100` es siempre cierto y tenemos un ciclo infinito siempre. Como en cada iteración del ciclo obtenemos un item de la sucesión y quieres saber si `numero1` es parte de la misma, el condicional debe ser:

```
while ultimo < numero1:
```

dónde ultimo es el ultimo item de la sucesión calculado en la ultima iteración. Esto causa que el ciclo termine si el último item de la sucesión calculado es igual (`numero1` pertenece a la sucesión) o mayor (`numero1` no pertenece a a la sucesión).

Por otro lado, te has complicado en el cálculo de cada item de la serie, solo necesitas dos variables, una que almacene el penúltimo item de la sucesión y otro el último calculado. En cada iteración, el nuevo item es la suma de estos dos valores anteriores y el penúltimo pasa a sel el antiguo último valor calculado:

```
temporal = penultimo
penultimo = ultimo
ultimo = penultimo + ultimo
```

En Python no necesitas la variable temporal, puedes hacer simplemente:

```
penultimo, ultimo = ultimo, penultimo + ultimo
```

El código puede quedar así:

```
numero1 = int(raw_input("Digite un numero de dos digitos: "))

if 9 < numero1 <= 99:
    penultimo = 0
    ultimo = 1

    while ultimo < numero1:
        penultimo, ultimo = ultimo, penultimo + ultimo

    if numero1 == ultimo:
        print "Si pertenece a las serie Fibonacci."

    else:
        print "El numero no pertenece a la serie Fibonacci."

else:
    print "Debe ingresar un numero de dos digitos"
```

Comment: buenas tardes como seria este código en pseint gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera proporcionar una aproximación distinta al problema aunque también
aprovecho para recordar que día a día python 2 está más próximo a declararse
obsoleto, y ya hace tiempo que debería haberle delegado su papel en el
aprendizaje y la creación de nuevo código a python 3.

La aproximación que propongo involucra generar la lista completa de valores
desde un inicio y luego simplemente se puede revisar si dicha lista contiene
el número buscado.

Para generar la lista se puede usar una función generadora como la
siguiente:

```
def generar_fibo_mayores_a_10(limite):
    a, b = 13, 21
    while a < limite:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

Mediante la cual puedes generar elementos hasta llegar a un "límite"
establecido por su único argumento. En el caso de este problema, el límite
sería 100, por lo que la lista completa se puede generar con:

```
serie = [f for f in generar_fibo_mayores_a_10(limite=100)]
```

Ahora si queremos saber si un número en concreto pertenece a la serie, basta
con hacer:

```
if numero in serie:
    print('Si pertenece')
else:
    print('No pertenece')
```

A fin de cuentas, seria prácticamente lo mismo si solo se va a consultar un
número como en este caso, aunque podría ser mucho más eficiente en caso de
requerir hacer el proceso varias veces.

Por si no queda claro como integrar estas ideas en tu código, aquí te dejo
el ejemplo completo:

```
def generar_fibo_mayores_a_10(limite):
    a, b = 13, 21
    while a < limite:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

serie = [f for f in generar_fibo_mayores_a_10(limite=100)]

numero = int(input('Digite un número de dos dígitos: '))
if 9 < numero <= 99:
    print('El número', ('si' if numero in serie else 'no'),
        'pertenece a la serie de fibonacci')
else:
    print('Debe ingresar un número de dos dígitos')
```

Comment: Gracias Saul Axel Martinez